# How to unit test when using LocaleKeys with easy_localization?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, localization

I'm unit testing a login method that uses `LocaleKeys.errors_msg.tr()` for an error message. I get the following error when my unit test runs:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'get' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: get("errors.msg")
```

How do I avoid this error so that my test passes?

Comment: Please post the code of the unit test so we can help with suggestions.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele The unit test code doesn't really matter in this case since I know that this line is causing the issue: `LocaleKeys.errors_msg.tr()`

Comment: Okay. Taking a look at the library

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it will help https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization/issues/199#issuecomment-655361113

Comment: @VictorEronmosele That does it, thanks!